# "Register My Computer" on a website

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am working on a secure web site, that will allow the user to register their computer, to avoid answering the primary security questions.

Is this just placing a cookie on their machine, and checking to see if the cookie exists?

Or do I need to retrieve the client machines ID data?

Comment: Is this an inernet or intranet site?

Cookies are horribly insecure and pretty easy to spoof, so I wouldn't go down that road.

Comment: This is an internet site. That was my thought about cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `combination` of `cookies`, `encryption` and `hashing algorithms` at your site to implement this.

Having said that, you should not save critical information bits on client computers and just save basic authorization and authentication details.

For example: Most of the websites provide you with the facility to remain logged in for specified period like yahoo mail etc.

you can use Tickets as well. See the following tutorial for details

**[Forms Authentication Configuration and Advanced Topics](http://www.asp.net/(S(pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3))/learn/security/tutorial-03-vb.aspx)**

Comment: what kind of hashing algorithms?

Comment: The encryption and hashing algorithms used by the forms authentication system to encrypt and validate the authentication ticket are customizable through the <machineKey> element in Web.config